# Why elasticseach 5.1 bool filter query runs slower than elasticsearch 1.5 filtered query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Following is my elastic search - 1.5 Query:

```
{
    "_source":["_id","spotlight"],
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "and":[
                    {"term":{"gender":"female"}},
                    {"range":{"lastlogindate":{"gte":"2016-10-19 12:39:57"}}}
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "filter":{
        "and":[
            {"term":{"maritalstatus":"1"}}
        ]
    },
    "sort":[{"member2_dummy7":{"order":"desc"}}],
    "size":"600",
    "aggs": {

        "maritalstatus": {

            "filter": {},
            "aggs" : {

                "filtered_maritalstatus": {"terms":{"field":"maritalstatus","size":5000}}
            }
        },

        "relationship": {

            "filter": {"term":{"maritalstatus":"1"}},
            "aggs" : {

                "filtered_relationship": {"terms":{"field":"relationship","size":5000}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I converted same query in elastic 5.1 as given below:

```
{
    "_source":["_id","spotlight"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {"term":{"gender":"female"}},
                {"range":{"lastlogindate":{"gte":"2016-10-19 12:39:57"}}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "post_filter": {"term":{"maritalstatus":"1"}},
    "sort":[{"member2_dummy7":{"order":"desc"}}],
    "size":"600",
    "aggs": {

        "maritalstatus": {

            "filter": {},
            "aggs" : {

                "filtered_maritalstatus": {"terms":{"field":"maritalstatus","size":5000}}
            }
        },

        "relationship": {

            "filter": {"term":{"maritalstatus":"1"}},
            "aggs" : {

                "filtered_relationship": {"terms":{"field":"relationship","size":5000}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ran both queries on two different AWS instances of same configuration and finally, I came to know that elastic-search 5.1 query is taking exactly twice time of elastic-search 1.5 query to execute.

Can some tell me why elastic-search 5.1 query is running slower than elastic-search 1.5???? Is there any more query optimization required to make it run fast??

For better testing, I removed everything from query and kept just one condition and tested using jmeter.

Following is my elastic-search 1.5 query:

```
{
    "_source":["_id","spotlight"],
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "and":[
                    {"term":{"gender":"female"}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my elastic-search 5.1 query:

```
{
    "_source":["_id","spotlight"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {"term":{"gender":"female"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Following is mapping in elastic-search 5.1:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "lowercase_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
            }
        },
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "profiles": {
            "properties": {
                "gender": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And below is mapping in elastic-search 1.5:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "string_lowercase": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": "lowercase"
                }
            }
        },
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "profiles": {
            "properties": {
                "gender": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "string_lowercase"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Elastic-search 1.5 query took 17 ms and Elastic-search 5.1 query took 23 ms. This is average time and this difference is consistent across all fields. I am not understanding why is it running slowly. Is elasticsearch 5.1 is slower than elasticsearch 1.5???

Comment: Can you clarify the logic of your query? Although I'm not sure about performance impact, I don't see the point of defining a post_filter nor sorting the results when specifying size=0.

Comment: To debug that, you can remove lines on each , test, remove lines test etc... First, remove ``sort``, then ``aggs`` , I believe lot people complain about bad performance since v5 :/ could be good to find exactly why.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux I have tested it many times. I tried all possible optimizations given in elastcisearch official website - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html. Accordingly, I made changes in query and field mapping and it improved speed of query but still it is running slower than elasticsearch 1.5. One more thing I observed is - if I remove aggregation then query is running very fast in elasticsearch 5.1. But if I add aggregation then it is running slower than elasticsearch 1.5.

Comment: I have added size = 600. I am using post_filter for calculating aggregation based on filter. e.g. for calculating aggregations on maritalstatus, I want to exclude query criteria of maritalstatus. I am considering this criteria for calculating aggregation on relationship. Still query in elasticsearch 1.5 is running faster than 5.1. I am not understanding what's going wrong in query which is causing it to run slower in elastcisearch 5.1.

Comment: Gloups, I didnt see ``"size":5000`` for aggs, can you try changing the collect mode (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_collect_mode)

Comment: I tried reducing size to 500 and upto 100. But no change observed in response time. Elasticsearch 5.1 is taking 2 times more time than elasticsearch 1.5. Elasticsearch 1.5 is executing query very fast with "size":5000. I didn't understand what's causing query to run slower in elasticsearch 5.1...